# Error al mostrar ciclo for

Tags: javascript

***Por qué no me muestra nada?***

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  
  var matriz = new Array(50);
  matriz.forEach(function(i) {
     document.getElementById("forEach").innerHTML += i + '\t';
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {  
  background-color: #E8A623;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<!--<!DOCTYPE html>--->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bucles</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Bucle for simple |  1 - 10 |</h1>
    <hr></hr>
  <i style="text-align: center;"><i id="forEach"></i></i>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nada de que? Especifica tu pregunta, saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The forEach() does not execute the function for array elements without values.
```

Como el compañero de arriba te ha mencionado.

Tu **array** esta lleno con valores **undefined**, los cuales no son considerados valores.

Answer (score 0):

Por que tu array solo esta lleno de Null, no hay nada que mostrar...

```js
  var matriz1 = new Array(50);
console.log('tu matriz');
console.log(matriz1);
var matriz = [1,2,3,4]
console.log('matriz llena');
console.log(matriz);
  matriz.forEach(function(i) {
     document.getElementById("forEach").innerHTML += i + '\t';
  });
```

```css
body {  
  background-color: #E8A623;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Bucle for simple |  1 - 10 |</h1>

  <i style="text-align: center;"><i id="forEach"></i></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu array esta vacio, debe ser llenado antes de ser recorrido de lo contrario te arrijara error.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var matriz = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  matriz.forEach(function(i) {
     document.getElementById("forEach").innerHTML += i + '\t';
  });
});
```

```css
body {  
  background-color: #E8A623;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bucles</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Bucle for simple |  1 - 10 |</h1>
    <hr></hr>
  <div style="text-align: center;" id="forEach"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```